# Custom properties inside dom-repeat is not rendering

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to get data-route work within dom-repeat.  It looks like custom properties are not rendered in the stamped html. So the selectors using data-route is not working.

In the below e.g., I have added data-route to  in first name. This property is not displayed in the rendered html.

http://jsbin.com/culamidiyu/1/edit?html,output

Edit: Something was wrong with the jsbin I posted. Updated jsbin, which, btw includes the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to stamp the custom attribute by adding '$' suffix. in my e.g., I used data-router$="[[item.route]]".